# Change the onclick attribute

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div class="hp_imp" onclick="location.href='https://www.abc.com/xyz';">        
</div>

<div class="hp_imp" onclick="location.href='https://www.abc.com/xyz/';">
</div>
```

The first div is the div with `https://www.abc.com/xyz` and I need to make the URL as `https://www.abc.com/xyz/` in the div itself dynamically.

Comment: What did you try? What didn't work? Please show us you've done some research effort.

Comment: I need to append a "/" to the onclick attribute `location.href='https://www.abc.com/xyz/`

Comment: Go to source and change it. :) As simple as that! If that's not possible, let us know what access you have.

Comment: i need it to do it with jquery

Comment: @DebjeetDas: If you're using jQuery (or, honestly, even if you're not) then you're much better off removing the inline JavaScript entirely and just binding to the matching elements in one place.  Something like: `$('div.hp_imp').click(function () { location.href = 'https://www.abc.com/xyz/'; });`  Then you don't run into this problem of having to change it everywhere.

Comment: What have you done ? Show us that and then only we will help you . You are not going to get a lot of help, if you do not show us your try outs .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.hp_imp').attr('onclick', function(i, val) { return val + '/'; });
```

Don't care much for inline event handlers, and you should consider removing it, but to change it, this should work.